# How can i write this javascript filter arguments function right?

Tags: javascript, filter, arguments

```
function terminate(arr) {
var args =[];
for(i=1;i<arguments.length;i++){
}


return arr.filter(e => e!=args[0]&& e!=args[1]&&e!=args[2]);
}

terminate([3, 5, 1, 2, 2], 2, 3, 5);
```

//terminate([3, 5, 1, 2, 2], 2, 3, 5) should return [1]

Comment: seeing as you're using es2015 already ... `function terminate(arr, ...args) => arr.filter(e => !args.includes(e));`

Comment: why did you remove the body of the for loop?

Comment: by the way, your original code worked correctly

Comment: The code still works by the way, those were just console.logs.I want to do this part =>```return arr.filter(e => e!=args[0]&& e!=args[1]&&e!=args[2]);```with a loop and not have to pick of the args array positions  myself.

Answer (score 0):

As *Jaromanda X* suggested, if you're using [ES2015/ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-class-definitions), then this is the best solution:

```
function terminate(arr, ...args) {
  return arr.filter(el => !args.includes(el));
}
```

**Edit**: Sorry! `Array.prototype.includes` isn't part of [ES2015/ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-class-definitions) it's part of [ES2016](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/). You'll need to use either `args.indexOf(el) === -1` (like the next example) or `!~args.indexOf(el)` (which uses a [Bitwise operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT)) as the filter predicate function if you're using [ES2015/ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-class-definitions).

For [ES5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) something like this would work:

```
function terminate(arr) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  return arr.filter(function (el) {
    return args.indexOf(el) === -1;
  });
}
```